# Uniquely Identify User without Credentials

Tags: swift

I am working on an app where the user can store data on the cloud. But I am not asking user to create credentials. I want to uniquely identify each user. Is UUID a good technique to create unique id's for the user.

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

But then the problem will be if the user deletes the app and installs again then there is no way of knowing who the user was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use the `let uuid = UUID().uuidString` if you want to identify a unique user if you don't have any other credentials.

> Represents UUID strings, which can be used to uniquely identify types,
>   interfaces, and other items.

If the user deletes the application then he/she will get a new `ID` and you can´t track the old `ID` with the user anymore. If you want to track the user even after deleting and reinstalling the application then you need some type of credentials.

Comment: But then the problem will be if the user deletes the app and installs again then there is no way of knowing who the user was.

Comment: Then the user will get a new ID, the ID is unique for each installation.

Comment: Yeah! But I am using the original UUID to store items to the cloud. If the person gets a new UUID then I cannot identify old items.

Comment: Thanks makes sense :)